# General topology (John Kelley) Exercise O chapter 3

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Show that the product for an arbitrary family of connected Topological spaces is connected.

The book gives the following hint:

Fix a point $x$ in the product and let $A$ be the set of all points $y$ such that there is a connected subset to which $x$ and $y$ belong. Show that $A$ is dense.

Now I have attempted this problem several times and done the finite case with no issues. My main question is how does this hint apply? All of the proofs I have seen related to this hint essentially goas follows:

i) Pick some fixed $x=x_i$ in the product which we denote $Y$ and $I$ is the indexing set

ii)Define $B=\{y\in Y: y=x_i\  \forall i \notin J\}$ where $J$ is some finite subset of of $I$

iii) Show that $B$ is connected

iv) Show that $B$ is dense in $Y$

v) then $Y=cl(B)$ is connected

I understand the idea but my main question is how does $A$ relate to $B$? It seems that $A$ is defined entirely differently unless they are equivalent in some way that I'm not thinking of.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez by John Kelley I edited it, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $x \in B$. If we can show that $B$ is connected, then $B \subset A$. That is the relation between $A$ and $B$, but it also means that we do not need to introduce $A$. It suffices to work with $B$.

I suggest to prove the connectedness of $B$ as follows.

Define $B_n =\{ y \in Y \mid y_i \ne x_i \text{ for at most } n \text{ indices } i \in I\}$. Then $B_n \subset B_{n+1}$ and $\bigcup_n B_n = B$. It therefore suffices to prove that all $B_n$ are connected. This can be done by induction.

The base case $n = 0$ is trivial because $B_0 = \{x\}$.

Now assume that $B_n$ is connected.

To show that $B_{n+1}$ is connected, it suffices to find for each $y \in B_{n+1} \setminus B_n$ a connected $C \subset Y$ such that $y \in C$ and $C \cap B_n \ne \emptyset$.

$y$ differs from $x$ in $n+1$ coordinates $i_1,\ldots i_{n+1}$. The space $Y$ is the product of connected spaces $Y_i$ with $i \in I$ and we define
$$f : Y_{i_{n+1}} \to Y, f(\eta)_i =  \begin{cases} \eta & i = i_{n+1} \\ y_i & i \ne i_{n+1} \end{cases}$$
This is a continuous map, thus its image $C  = f(Y_{i_{n+1}})$ is connected. Clearly $y = f(y_{i_{n+1}}) \in C$ and $y' = f(x_{i_{n+1}}) \in C$. The point $y'$ differs from $x$ in the $n$ coordinates $i_1,\ldots,i_n$, thus $y' \in B_n$.

To check the density of $B$ in $Y$, recall that a basis for the product topology on $Y$ is given by the sets $\prod_i U_i$ with open $U_i \subset Y_i$ such that $U_i = Y_i$ for all but finitely many $i \in I$. Given $z \in Y$ and a basic open neigborhood  $U = \prod_i U_i$ of $z$, let $i_1,\ldots, i_k$ denote the indices such that $U_{i_r} \ne Y_{i_r}$. Then the point $y$ with coordinates
$$y_i  = \begin{cases} z_i & i = i_1,\ldots, i_k \\ x_i & \text{else} \end{cases}$$
belongs to $B \cap U$, i.e. $B \cap U \ne\emptyset$.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how we know $B$ is a subset of $A$? I know that elements of $A$ and $B$ will differ by finitely many coordinates but how does that tell us that any element of $B$ will belong to $A$?

Comment: @Ook We consider a fixed $x \in Y$. Then $A$ is defined as the set of all points $y$ such that there is a connected subset to which $x$ and $y$ belong. I showed that $B$ is a connected subset such  that $x \in B$. Thus each $y \in B$ is an element of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

One way to prove is to invoke the following characterization proposition.

Proposition 1: Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. Then the following
are equivalent:

(a) $\tau$ is connected.

(b) If $f:X\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ is a continuous function (where $\{0,1\}$
is equipped with the discrete topology), then $f$ is a constant function.

---

We also need this:

Proposition 2: Let $I$ be an index set. For each $i\in I$, let $(X_{i},\tau_{i})$
be a topological space. Let $(X,\tau)=\otimes_{i\in I}(X_{i},\tau_{i})$
be the product space. Let $\pi_{i}:X\rightarrow X_{i}$ be the canonical
projection. Let $(x_{\alpha}):D\rightarrow X$ be a net on $X$ (where
$(D,\preceq)$ is a directed system) and $x\in X$. Then the following
are equivalent.

(a) $x_{\alpha}\rightarrow x$, with respect to the product topology
$\tau$.

(b) For each $i\in I$, $\pi_{i}(x_{\alpha})\rightarrow\pi_{i}(x)$,
with respect to the topology $\tau_{i}$.

Proof: Clearly $(a)\Rightarrow(b)$ because $\pi_{i}$ is continuous.
Conversely, suppose that $(b)$ holds. Let $U$ be an arbitrary open
neighborhood of $x$. Then there exist a finite index set $I_{1}\subseteq I$
and open sets $V_{i}\in\tau_{i}$ ($i\in I_{1})$ such that $x\in\cap_{i\in I_{1}}\pi_{i}^{-1}(V_{i})\subseteq U.$
Note that $V_{i}$ is an open neighborhood of $x(i)$, so by assumption
$(b)$, for each $i\in I_{1}$, there exists $\alpha_{i}\in D$ such
that $x_{\alpha}(i)\in V_{i}$ whenever $\alpha_{i}\preceq\alpha$.
Since $I_{1}$ is finite, we can find $\beta\in D$ such that $\alpha_{i}\preceq\beta$
for all $i\in I_{1}$. Finally, if $\alpha\in D$ and $\beta\preceq\alpha$,
then $\alpha_{i}\preceq\alpha$ for each $i\in I_{1}$ and hence $x_{\alpha}(i)\in V_{i}$
for each $i\in I_{1}$. That is, $x_{\alpha}\in\cap_{i\in I_{1}}\pi_{i}^{-1}(V_{i})\subseteq U$.
Therefore, $x_{\alpha}\rightarrow x$ with respect to the product
topology $\tau$.

---

In the following, we invoke the Axiom of Choice implicitly.

Proposition 3 (Product of connected spaces is connected): Let $I$ be an index set. For each $i\in I$, let $(X_{i},\tau_{i})$
be a connected topological space. Let $X=\prod_{i\in I}X_{i}$ and
$\tau=\otimes_{i\in I}\tau_{i}$ be the product topology. Then $(X,\tau)$
is a connected topological space.

Proof: Let $f:X\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ be a continuous function. Let
$a,b\in X$ be arbitrary. We go to show that $f(a)=f(b)$ and it will
follow that $f$ is a constant function.

By the Well-Ordering Principle (which is equivalent to the Axiom of
Choice), $I$ can be well-ordered. Hence, without loss of generality,
we may assume that $I$ is an ordinal. Note that $a$ is a map $a:I\rightarrow \cup_{i\in I} X_i$
such that $a(i)\in X_{i}$, $i\in I$. We denote $a=(a_{0},a_{1},a_{2},\ldots)$
(Remember that elements of $I$ are ordinals). Similarly, denote $b=(b_{0},b_{1},b_{2},\ldots)$.
For $i\in I$, let $\pi_{i}:X\rightarrow X_{i}$ be the canonical
projection. For each $i\in I+1$ (Remember that $I$ is an ordinal,
so $I+1$ is well-defined. Moreover, $I\in I+1$. For ordinals $i,j$,
we will use the notations $j\in i$ and $j<i$ interchangeably), let
$x^{i}=(x_{0}^{i},x_{1}^{i},\ldots)\in X$ be defined by $x_{j}^{i}=\begin{cases}
b_{j}, & \mbox{if }j<i\\
a_{j}, & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}.$ Note that $x^{0}=a$ and $x^{I}=b$.

Consider a "formula" $\varphi(i)$, where the free variable $i$
ranges over the ordinal $I+1$.

$\varphi(i):$ $f(a)=f(x^{i})$. Note $\varphi(I)$ reads $f(a)=f(b)$.
We go to prove that $\varphi(I)$ is true by transfinite induction.

Let $i\in I+1$ be arbitrary. Suppose that $\varphi(j)$ is true for
all $j<i$. We go to show that $\varphi(i)$ is true. Consider two
cases.

Case 1: $i$ is a not a limit ordinal. If $i=0$, clearly $\varphi(0)$
is true. Suppose that $i\neq0$, then $i$ has a unique predecessor
$k$, i.e., $i=k+1$. Define $\theta:X_{k}\rightarrow X$ by $\theta(\xi)=y=(y_{0},y_{1},y_{2}\ldots)$,
where $y_{j}=\begin{cases}
\xi, & \mbox{if }j=k\\
x_{j}^{k}, & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}.$ That is, $\theta(\xi)$ is obtained by replacing the $k$-th component
of $x^{k}$ by $\xi$ and leaving other components unchanged. Observe
that $\pi_{j}\circ\theta$ is continuous for each $j$ (if $j=k$,
then it is the identity map on $X_{k}$; otherwise, it is a constant
map). By the universal property of product topology, $\theta$ is
continuous. In particular, $f\circ\theta:X_{k}\rightarrow\{0,1\}$
is continuous. By Prop 1 and the connectedness of $(X_k,\tau_k)$, $f\circ\theta$ is a constant function,
so $f\circ\theta(a_{k})=f\circ\theta(b_{k})$. Note that $\theta(a_{k})=x^{k}$
and $\theta(b_{k})=x^{k+1}=x^{i}$. Therefore, $f(x^{k})=f(x^{i})$.
Since $\varphi(k)$ is true, it follows that $f(a)=f(x^{k})=f(x^{i})$.
Hence, $\varphi(i)$ is true.

Case 2: $i$ is a limit ordinal. Note that $(i,\leq)$ is a directed
system. Therefore, $(x^{j})_{j\in i}$ is a net in $X$. We go to
show that $x^{j}\rightarrow x^{i}$ (as $j\rightarrow\infty)$ with
respect to the product topology by invoking Prop 2. Let $k\in I$
be aribtrary. We go to show that $\pi_{k}(x^{j})\rightarrow\pi_{k}(x^{i})$.
Further consider two sub-cases

Case 2.1: $i\leq k$. In this case, $\pi_{k}(x^{j})=x_{k}^{j}=a_{k}$
for all $j<i$ and $\pi_{k}(x^{i})=x_{k}^{i}=a_{k}$. Therefore, $\pi_{k}(x^{j})\rightarrow\pi_{k}(x^{i})$
as $j\rightarrow\infty$.

Case 2.2: $i>k$. In this case, for $k<j<i$, we have that $\pi_{k}(x^{j})=x_{k}^{j}=b_{k}$
and $\pi_{k}(x^{i})=x_{k}^{i}=b_{k}$. Therefore, $\pi_{k}(x^{j})\rightarrow\pi_{k}(x^{i})$
as $j\rightarrow\infty$.

This shows that $x^{j}\rightarrow x^{i}$ (as $j\rightarrow\infty)$
with respect to the product topology. Since $\varphi(j)$ is true
for each $j<i$, we have that $f(a)=f(x^{j})$. Letting $j\rightarrow\infty$
and by continuity of $f$, we obtain $f(a)=f(x^{i})$.

This shows that $\varphi(i)$ is true.

By transfinite induction, $\varphi(i)$ is true for all $i\in I+1$.
In particular, $\varphi(I)$ is true. That is, $f(a)=f(b)$.